# Block select all everywhere except in inputs

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I'm writing an Electron app with an Angular renderer and want to disable keyboard shortcuts like select all (Ctrl+A), but still want to be able to select all in inputs/textareas.

So first I have this in my Angular main.js to disable the keyboard shortcut:

```
document.onkeydown = function(e: KeyboardEvent) {
  if (e.ctrlKey && e.code === "KeyA") {
    return false;
  }
};
```

and then I want to make individual exceptions for specific inputs/textareas in my component something like this:

Template:

```
<textarea (keydown)="rejectInput($event)"></textarea>
```

Component:

```
public rejectInput(event: KeyboardEvent) {
  if (event.ctrlKey && event.code === "KeyA") {
    // Opposite of event.preventDefault() or something...
  }
}
```

I want to do the same for Ctrl+C to be able to copy the text in the inputs as well.

Can this be achieved somehow? Am I on the right track or thinking entirely wrong?

Comment: Do you really want to disable just "select all", or selection in general?

Comment: In general would be nice, but I haven't been able to do that. I have `body {
  user-select: none;
}` in my global styles but that doesn't help AFAIK